# Entity Framework Core - recreate database from the CLI

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

During development, I often want to clear out the data in my Entity Framework (SQL) database and rebuild the empty table structure using existing migrations. I'd like to do this with dotnet ef commands.

Dropping the DB is easy:

```
dotnet ef database drop {OPTIONAL: --project MyProject --context MyContext}
```

I had thought I could rescaffold with the update command:

```
dotnet ef database update {OPTIONAL: --project MyProject --context MyContext}
```

But this fails with a "login failed for user" error. My DB is hosted in Azure, so I'm having to manually recreate the database in the portal, update my connection string and then run the update command.

Comment: Very interesting that the user has permissions to drop the database, but not create a new one... This might(?) just be normal on SQL Azure.

Comment: A support ticket might be the best thing.